# How can I send json data from my jsp page to a spring rest controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to send data from a jsp page, which includes `datetime`, `zoneid`, checked checkbox having values and non-checked checkbox having null value.

I am sending all these as json to my spring rest controller but when I opened in debug mode, I found the controller received only two data(one of the checkbox that I clicked and submit input value). I don't get where all other data got lost.

Also, when I am sending data through postman everything working fine but don't know why I am having trouble sending from jsp page.

Also I was initially using `@RequestBody` in controller to get pojo class object type data but it was giving content-type unsupported error so I replaced `@RequestBody` with `@RequestParam` and now using map type data. Now that error is not coming, But I still don't understand why it was giving error.

`jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
       pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<!-- Static content -->
<script
       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script
       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form   id = "schedulejob" action="scheduleJob" method="POST">
<label>
<input type="checkbox"  id = "corporateClientCare" name="corporateClientCare" value="corporateClientCare" class="input_checkbox"> CorporateClientCare 
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id = "dayforce" name="dayforce" value="dayforce" class="input_checkbox"> Dayforce  </label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id = "tss" name="tss" value="tss" class="input_checkbox"> TSS </label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id = "multimax"  name="multimax" value="multimax" class="input_checkbox"> Multimax</label>
<label> <input type="checkbox" id = "arcot"  name="arcot" value="arcot" class="input_checkbox"> Arcot <br/></label> 
<input type="datetime-local" id="dateTime" name = "dateTime" value="2019-06-04T15:25:33">    
<input type="submit" name="Scheduler" value="Scheduler" class="submit"/></form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#schedulejob").submit(function(){
var scheduleRequest = {};
scheduleRequest["corporateClientCare"] = verifychecked("corporateClientCare");
scheduleRequest["dayforce"] = verifychecked("dayforce");
scheduleRequest["tss"] = verifychecked("tss");
scheduleRequest["multimax"] = verifychecked("multimax");
scheduleRequest["arcot"] = verifychecked("arcot");
scheduleRequest["dateTime"] = document.getElementById("dateTime").value;
scheduleRequest["timeZone"] = "Asia/Kolkata";
$.ajax({

type : form.attr('method'),
contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
url : form.attr('action'),
data : JSON.stringify(scheduleRequest),
dataType : 'json',              
success : function(data) {

                    }
                });
         });

        function verifychecked(value) {
        var varr = '';
        if(document.getElementById(value).checked)
        {
           varr = value;
        }
        else{
            varr = null;
        }
          return varr;

    }
    });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

`controller`

```
@Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

@PostMapping("/scheduleJob")
public ResponseEntity<ScheduleResponse> scheduleJobs(@RequestBody ScheduleRequest  scheduleRequest) {
    try {
        System.out.println("___________IN CONTROLLER__________");
        System.out.println("--------------zone-----------");
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(scheduleRequest.getDateTime(), scheduleRequest.getTimeZone());
        System.out.println("--------------date is-----------" + dateTime);
        System.out.println("dateTime is " + dateTime);
        if(dateTime.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now())) {
            ScheduleResponse scheduleResponse = new ScheduleResponse(false,
                    "dateTime must be after current time");
            System.out.println("--------------1-------------------");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(scheduleResponse);
        }
//rest code
```

I am not getting the data. When I checked in debug mode, I found my mao had only 2 keys and I don't understand why it did not capture rent data.

Comment: Verify that the variable scheduleRequest has all the data set while it is being converted to json in jquery. Also use @ResponseBody instead of RequestParam since you are setting the data to request body of the request.Request param is used when the parameters are expected as a part of the request url

Comment: I am using '@RequestBody' only. And when I am sending request from postman, everything working fine. I am new to UI so couldn't spot the error yet but have figured out that the script is not working at all. when the form is submitted only form data is going that's y when using @requestparam I am not getting error as request is going through header. Can't figure out why the control is not going to script at all . Also when trying to normally send data through form, the datetime-local value from form is sending null value. Why is it sending null value and not datetime value entered.

Answer (score 0):

In your case since you have provided the action and method parameter in the form and also since you have a submit button on the form , on clicking the submit button , a POST request is fired and the content type for this request will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. So, if you want this to be changed to json , you must use `enctype` the attribute like :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But unfortunatly for you HTML provides no way to generate **JSON from form data**.
If you really want to handle it from the client, then you would have to resort to using JavaScript

So you must **first disable the html form submit** and then collect the data and using jquery ajax do a post request with the content type set as `application/json`.

Try the following jquery for triggering the jquery form submit :

```
$("#schedulejob").on('submit',function( event ) { 

event.preventDefault();

var scheduleRequest = {};
scheduleRequest["corporateClientCare"] = verifychecked("corporateClientCare");
scheduleRequest["dayforce"] = verifychecked("dayforce");
scheduleRequest["tss"] = verifychecked("tss");
scheduleRequest["multimax"] = verifychecked("multimax");
scheduleRequest["arcot"] = verifychecked("arcot");
scheduleRequest["dateTime"] = document.getElementById("dateTime").value;
scheduleRequest["timeZone"] = "Asia/Kolkata";

$.ajax({

type : form.attr('method'),
contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
url : form.attr('action'),
data : JSON.stringify(scheduleRequest),
dataType : 'json',              
success : function(data) {

                    }
                });
         });

        function verifychecked(value) {
        var varr = '';
        if(document.getElementById(value).checked)
        {
           varr = value;
        }
        else{
            varr = null;
        }
          return varr;

  }); 
});
```

In your code , you were not passing the 'event' to the function.According to the jquery documentation you should do that :Refer [link](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

or instead of using the input type submit button use the following :

```
<button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit Form</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitBtn").click(function(){        
   // Submit the form using jquery like above
});
});
```

Comment: same error I am getting.. its submitting form data and not going to script :|

Comment: @charchitashukla The issue that i saw in your code was that you forgot to invoke the event.preventDefault() to prevent default form submission from happening and you were not passing event object to the function as in .submit() jquery api doc. Can you try using the code i provided in the answer.Have updated it using jquery .on() , you may use .submit() if you choose to both are same

Comment: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarymg9mfSGVxu5ndexw;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Comment: Is the default form submit still getting triggered ? even after calling the preventDefault() ?

Comment: yes, the default form submit is still getting triggered

Comment: If the first solution did not work for you, can you try replacing the submit button with normal button like type="button" and trigger the ajax on onClick or like i have done ? It will be easier if you could provide a link to your code or sample code so that we can try the same.